# Timed Triggers and Animation

Tags: android, animation

Can you please help me answer the following questions?

1. How do people usually implement a timed event in games?

   Example: You reach some point in time and something happens like a new wave of enemies appears or something similar.
2. What is the best way to make sprite animations?

   Example: Explosions in an android game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Every time round your game loop you will want to record the elapsed time (or delta time.) This means you could keep track of the time past since the game start and the time it took to execute one iteration of your loop (the latter is good for time based movement.)

2) Depends really, I'm assuming this is 2D so I personally use sprite maps (google it) and then after x seconds I will change the image that is being rendered to the next on in the animation sequence. Animation sequences normally consist of "frames" and after x seconds have passed then move to the next frame

Answer (score 0):

1 - Each frame/cycle of your game, record the time, then get the difference between the previous cycle's and the current cycle's time. This is how much time has elapsed since the last frame/cycle. Objects can then have timers that subtract the elapsed time each cycle, and do things when their timers are <= 0.

2 - My preference for game development is [flixel](http://www.flixel.org), which does a lot of the dirty work for you. If you want to use pixel images instead of vector graphics, you should take a look at flixel. It has a framework that makes working with images and spritesheet animations a breeze. At the very least you can figure out how flixel handles them and write your own methods based on what you learned. If you want vector graphics, however, you'll need some other solution.

Comment: oh thanks! but i can't use such thing as engines(i need to make my own) in my project